# Pass the output of ls to diff

Tags: unix, diff, ls

I have one file that contains a list of files from a server, and a local folder that I compare to that manifest. Obviously, I do 'ls -1 > listing_local' and then diff that file with listing_server.

But is it possible to diff the manifest and the output of ls immediately to the diff command?

Answer (score 4):

In bash:

```
diff listing_server <(ls -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) the output of a unix command into the input of another.

```
ls -1 | diff file_goes_here -
```

Comment: this won't work

Comment: Now it does. That's what I get for not testing it first.

Answer (score 2):

```
diff listing <(ls -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -1 | diff listing_server -
```

Comment: The `-1` is unnecessary if the output is not to a terminal.